# Emitting intermediate keys in MapReduce through a for-loop - have I misunderstood MapReduce? Basic example included.

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

So I have a collection of emails and what I want to do is use them to output unique triplets (sender email, receiver email, timestamp) like so:

```
user1@stackoverflow.com    user2@stackoverflow.com    09/12/2009 16:45
user1@stackoverflow.com    user9@stackoverflow.com    09/12/2009 18:45
user3@stackoverflow.com    user4@stackoverflow.com    07/05/2008 12:29
```

In the above example user 1 sent a single email to multiple recipients (user 2 and user 9). To store the recipients, I created a data structure `EdgeWritable`(implements `WritableComparable)`that will hold the **Sender** and **Recipient** email addresses as well as a **Timestamp**.

My mapper looks like this:

```
private final EdgeWritable edge = new EdgeWritable(); // Data structure for triplets.
private final NullWritable noval = NullWritable.get(); 

...

@Override
public void map(Text key, BytesWritable value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    byte[] bytes = value.getBytes();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), "UTF-8");
    String from = null; // Sender's Email address
    ArrayList<String> recipients = new ArrayList<String>(); // List of recipients' Email addresses  
    long millis = -1; // Date

    // Parse information from file
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.startsWith("From:")) {
            from = procFrom(stripCommand(line, "From:")); // Get sender e-mail address.
        } else if (line.startsWith("To:")) {
            procRecipients(stripCommand(line, "To:"), recipients); // Populate recipients into a list. 
        } else if (line.startsWith("Date:")) {
            millis = procDate(stripCommand(line, "Date:")); // Get timestamp.

        if (line.equals("")) { // Empty line indicates the end of the header
            break;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();

    // Emit EdgeWritable as intermediate key containing Sender, Recipient and Timestamp. 
    if (from != null && recipients.size() > 0 && millis != -1) { 
        //EdgeWritable has 2 Text values (ew[0] and ew[1]) and a Timestamp. ew[0] is the sender, ew[1] is a recipient.
        edge.set(0, from); // Set ew[0]  
        for(int i = 0; i < recipients.size(); i++) {
            edge.set(1, recipients.get(i)); // Set edge from sender to each recipient i. 
            edge.setTS(millis); // Set date. 
            context.write(edge, noval); // Emit the edge as an intermediate key with a null value. 
        }
    }
}

...
```

My reducer simply formats the date and outputs the edges:

```
public void reduce(EdgeWritable key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String date = MailReader.sdf.format(edge.getTS());
    out.set(edge.get(0) + " " + edge.get(1) + " " + date); // same edge from Mapper (an EdgeWritable). 
    context.write(noval, out); // same noval from Mapper (a NullWritable).
}
```

Using EdgeWritable as the intermediate key and NullWritable as the value (in mapper) is a requirement, I'm not permitted to use other methods. This is my first Hadoop / MapReduce program and I just wanted to know that I'm going in the right direction. I have looked at plenty of MapReduce examples online and have never seen key/value pairs being emitted in a for-loop the way I have done it. I feel like I'm missing some sort of trick here, but using a for-loop in this way is the only approach I can think of.

Is this 'bad'? I hope this is clear but please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Map method gets called for each record, so your array list is having only 1 record for every call.  Declare your array list at class level so that u can store values for all records. Then in clean up method you can do the emit logic which you have written inside map. Try this and let me know if that works.

Comment: I must say that as it is, the program works. It outputs the emails exactly how I want them to. I'm just wondering if using a for-loop to emit the edges like this is 'cheating' or if it is seen as bad practice. I have never seen it in a MapReduce example. What do you think?

Comment: Nothing wrong in emitting them in loop. You can emit multiple many values from your map method.